# VPN to connect personal devices

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop

I want to connect my family devices in a single network wherever they are with no/minimal extra software installing. The best solution I think is with VPN, but I don't want to use that VPN for browsing the web, just to connect this devices with each other and maybe RDP.

What I found right now is 2 solutions:

1. [Microsoft Azure free Private Network](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/BrowseResourceBlade/resourceType/Microsoft.Network%2FvirtualNetworks) to create personal VPN and connect these devices to it via built-in Windows and Android VPN provider (I don't know if this is how this works)
2. Using [SoftEther](https://www.softether.org/) to create a VPN server on my PC and connect those devices with the same built-in providers (similar to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cbtham/2017/03/07/diy-build-your-own-vpn-with-microsoft-azure-oss/) but on personal device)

Where are the best solution for my situation or maybe a better and simpler one is available.

Comment: I'd recommend OpenVPN running on your router, and you can specify in the server networks to forward, preventing the VPN from being used for web traffic.  Just an FYI: you'll be limited by the upload speed of the ISP plan the remote device is behind.  If you don't have a static WAN IP from the ISP, you'll also need to purchase a DDNS subscription.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I achieved this by using [ZeroTier One](https://zerotier.com), it has exactly what I wanted, to connect locally my personal devices via VPN for free.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install extra software, and have a server on a known/static IP address. OpenVPN is a typical solution.

You don't generally route web traffic differently to other traffic as routers and VPNs typically route based on IP address rather then port. It sounds like you want to set up a VPN but simply don't want to publish a default route, which means traffic between VPN systems are encrypted but other traffic just goes out the Internet connection as normal.